# Python convert string to variable name

Tags: string, variables, python-3.x, dictionary

Im aware that this may come up as a duplicate but so far I haven't found (or should that be understood) an answer to what Im looking for.

I have a list of strings and want to convert each one into a variable name which I then assign something to. I understand that I may need a dict for this but I am unfamiliar with them as I am relatively new to python and all the examples I have seen so far deal with values whilst I'm trying something different.

Im after something like:

```
list = ['spam', 'eggs', 'ham']

for i in range(len(list)):
    list[i] = rat.readColumn(ratDataset, list[i])
```

where the first list[i] is a variable name and not a string. The second list[i] is a string (and for context is the name of a column Im reading from a raster attribute table (rat))

Essentially I want each string within the list to be set as a variable name.

The idea behind this is that I can create a loop without having to write out the line for each variable I want, with matching rat column name (the string). Maybe there is a beer way of doing this than I am suggesting?

Comment: Just use a dictionary, you should keep data out of variable names

Comment: Could you provide some helps to how i might do this?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
lst = ['spam', 'eggs', 'ham']
d = {}   # empty dictionary
for name in lst:
    d[name] = rat.readColumn(ratDataset, name)
```

Do not use `list` for your identifiers as it is a type identifier and you would mask its existence. The for loop can iterate directly for the elements inside -- no need to construct index and use it aganist the list. The `d['spam']` will be one of your *variables*.

Although, it is also possible to create *the real variable names* like `spam`, `eggs`, `ham`, you would not probably do that as the effect would be useless.

Comment: :) Arthur was 14 seconds faster.

Answer (score 1):

Here comes a simple dictionary use :

```
variables = ['spam', 'eggs', 'ham']
data = {}

datum = 0

for variable in variables:
    data[variable] = datum
    datum+=1

print(data)
print("value : ",data[variables[2]])
```

It gives as result :

```
{'eggs': 1, 'ham': 2, 'spam': 0}
value : 2
```

NB : don't use `list` as a variable name, list is a type identifier that you can use to transform an object into a list if possible (`list("abc")==['a', 'b', 'c']`) and you are overriding it with your value list right now.

Answer (score 0):

one way is setting the variable name as a string and changing a part or all of it via `format()` method and then using the string as a varibale via `vars()[STRING]`

```py
import numpy as np
X1= np.arange(1,10)                                                                                                                                
y1=[i**2 for i in X1]                                                                                                                                
X2= np.arange(-5,5)                                                                                                                                
y2=[i**2 for i in X2]                                                                                                                          
for i in range(1,3): 
    X = 'X{}'.format(i) 
    y = 'y{}'.format(i) 
    print('X_{}'.format(i) , vars()[X])
    print('y_{}'.format(i) , vars()[y])
```

Output:

```py
X_1 [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
y_1 [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
X_2 [-5 -4 -3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3  4]
y_2 [25, 16, 9, 4, 1, 0, 1, 4, 9, 16]
```